# ♥Veni♀Vidi♂Vici☠

Tags: riddle, literature

Third in a line, bred to be realistic,
Somewhat compassionate, not too sadistic.

Taught a new game, I learned how to rack 'em.
In spite of their cheating, I improv'd and sacked 'em.

Surprised how you find me? The game ended victorious!
Ironically infamous, disgraced and inglorious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> [Ender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game).

♥Veni♀Vidi ♂Vici☠

> This is the title of Chapter 11.

Third in a line, bred to be realistic,

> You were a "Third" because you were the third child. You were allowed to be born because the government liked your siblings but thought they were too extreme.

Somewhat compassionate, not too sadistic.

> You were between the extremes of your sister's compassion and your brother's sadism.

Taught a new game, I learned how to rack 'em.

> You became very good at the war games at the school. *Rack 'em* is a play on Mazer Rackham, who trained you (credit to Hellion).

In spite of their cheating, I improv'd and sacked 'em.

> The other team cheated to try to make the games fairer.

Surprised how you find me? The game ended victorious!

> You passed the final test.

Ironically infamous, disgraced and inglorious.

> This resulted in the annihilation of the buggers' home planet.

Comment: This has to be correct. I was going to post this answer after I read it as well.

Comment: There's also a reference to another major character in line 3....

Comment: @Hellion Nice find! Added.

Comment: does the chapter title include the emoticons in the original book?

Comment: @NH I don't think so.

Comment: makes me wonder if there is a special meaning to them, then... Looks like "Love came, a woman saw, and a man conquered death". But that sounds like a whole 'nother story, and doesn't seem to fit with the main text.

Comment: @NH Vini Vidi Vici is only 12 characters, I needed 15 for the title. :) The subject was balanced between rot13(ybivat fvfgre naq ivpvbhf oebgure).

Comment: LOL @ "The other team cheated to try to make the games fairer." I was thinking of the character from the third line supposedly cheating in the tests before the "final exam," making him improvise new tactics.

Comment: @Chowzen It's been a while since I read the book, but remembered something about the organizers rigging the matches to give Ender a challenge.

Comment: @Chowzen, if it is correct, you should probably accept it.

Comment: @NH. [I always do,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22519/chowzen?tab=questions) but [as discussed here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/how-fast-should-i-accept-a-correct-answer), I usually wait for about a day to do so after the correct answer has been given in order not to dissuade others from looking, commenting, in some cases giving a more correct/complete answer. Case in point, if I had accepted this as soon as it was posted, the reference in line 3 may not have been noticed by Hellion and therefore not included in the answer.